# Make flex items grow equally (and expand parent container)

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox, web-deployment

I would like to dynamically grow the content in some flex items and all other items to always be the size of the biggest sibling. My problem is that I also would like the items to make the container grow which has no fixed dimensions. Here is a fiddle, should be easier to understand: https://jsfiddle.net/uxjs5eL6/3/ I want to be able to press the button n times and all orange squares stay an equal size while still growing.

Is this even possible with flexbox? If not, how could I achieve desired effect?

Heres the code from JSFiddle as I need to provide some:

```js
var dimension = 180;

function grow() {
  document.getElementById("grower").style.height = dimension + "px";
  document.getElementById("grower").style.width = dimension + "px";
  dimension = dimension + 20;
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: 200px;
}

.item {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  background-color: orange;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

#grower {
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="grow()">
Grow!
</button>

<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div id="grower">
    
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: like this: https://jsfiddle.net/gk2fjb7p/ ?

Answer (score 0):

If you set specific width to the element then flex-box will not work, it is important to set width? If you only set height and with as `100%` then it will work. Eventually you can set `overflow: hidden` to the .item but I assume that cutting of content will be bad

Comment: I didn't set a width, the child has a width. If I set the childs with to 100% it will only take the available space of the item and that is not what I want.